# Modifying current rewrite rules to force SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, url-rewriting

I want all of the pages on my website to force an SSL connection. Currently I have this in place...

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above rules were inspired by the internet and I do not fully understand them. I tried changing the last line to `RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]` (note the *https* part).

When I test the redirect using http://www.domain.com/path-to-here I am redirected to https://www.domain.com/.

In short, the ultimate goal is to force www and https while preserving all original paths.

Ex:

- http://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
- http://domain.com/this-is-my-path-1/ -> https://www.domain.com/this-is-my-path-1/
- https://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
- https://domain.com/this-is-my-path-1/ -> https://www.domain.com/this-is-my-path-1/
- http://www.domain.com -> https://www.domain.com
- http://www.domain.com/this-is-my-path-1/ -> https://www.domain.com/this-is-my-path-1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```